# How to create custom loading spinner in Ionic 3

Tags: ionic3, spinner

I have an app which has been built with Ionic 1. I upgraded this app to Ionic 3. While doing this, I am having a trouble. It is that I can't create the same spinner as Ionic 1 in Ionic 3.
Here is a video with the spinner in Ionic 1.

[Loading spinner video for Ionic 1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mfdrxjshumkemrb/loading-spinner.mov?dl=0)

Also, here is a [video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wyan1ye8c5at3xu/3-loading-spinner.mov?dl=0)  which I created in Ionic 3.
Look forward to receiving a good solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this code to create custom loader.

```css
presentLoadingCustom() {
  let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
    spinner: 'hide',
    content: `
      <div class="custom-spinner-container">
        <div class="custom-spinner-box">
           <img src="assets/imgs/loader.gif" />
        </div>
      </div>`,
    duration: 5000
  });

  loading.onDidDismiss(() => {
    console.log('Dismissed loading');
  });

  loading.present();
}
```

after that create a animated gif for loading purpose. For now, you can use this site to download the gif loader [gif](https://loading.io). Place this gif to the assets folder and link the gif in the `.custom-spinner-box` class.

Comment: Hello Ajoy,
Thank you for your help. Can you help me for one more thing?

Comment: Yes, what's that?

Comment: I want to solve this problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52628778/how-to-use-custom-svg-as-refreshingspinner-in-ion-refresher-ionic-3/52653847?noredirect=1#comment92264272_52653847

Comment: you want a loader.. while scrolling and loading new data?

Comment: I want a custom refreshingIcon for ion-refresher.

Answer (score 0):

While you are want a custom refresher, for this you need some modification in the code. Here it is -

Add this in app.scss file

```css
  [ng-reflect-name="customcircles"]{
    background-image: url('https://loading.io/spinners/cutiefox/lg.cutie-fox-spinner.gif');
    background-size: cover;
  }
```

```html
 <ion-refresher (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event)">
    <ion-refresher-content 
    refreshingSpinner="customcircles">
    </ion-refresher-content>
  </ion-refresher>
```

and Add this in .HTML file. 
I hope you got it.

Comment: thank you so much. i will try it. and let you know about the result.

Comment: i tried it and it works. but you don't have any idea to keep the pullingIcon?

Comment: If you want to use icon.. then you can go with ionic default icons or made it your own loader icon with HTML SCSS.