# How to use custom SVG as refreshingSpinner in ion-refresher Ionic 3

Tags: ionic3, spinner

I've been upgrading **Ionic v1** to **v3**. It's almost done. But I am not making any progress because of one problem. It's just create a refreshingSpinner like the following video.

> https://www.dropbox.com/s/h820nz759bcqhvn/refresher-spinner.mov?dl=0

And [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ldpwtaegqgbf7on/refresher-spinner-3.mov?dl=0) is the video which I've used the default spinner.

Hope to get a good solution for this trouble.

Comment: so did you try to use the refresher? https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/refresher/Refresher/ and if so what was the problem - you don't know how to use custom SVG?

Comment: yes, I am using it for the pull to refresh. but it supports only dedicated spinners for refreshingSpinner attribute. I need to use custom spinner for it.

Comment: the documentation says you can use your custom one. If you could share your current implementation via stackblitz.com I could show how you can use custom svg

Comment: okay. I will share this question on stackblitz.com

Comment: could you let me know how to share it via stackblitz.com? I don't know how to use it.

Comment: hello Sergy, how are you? i shared the current implementation via stackblitz.com.
Editor URL: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-jtupjr
App URL: https://ionic-jtupjr.stackblitz.io
Embed URL: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-jtupjr?embed=1&file=pages/home/home.ts
Hope your kind support.

Comment: Cool i will give u answer in an hour or so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So according to ionic's documentation you can customize the refresher's template by introducing your own template inside "ion-refresher" tags:

```
<ion-refresher (ionRefresh)="loadData($event)">
// your own customized view goes in here
</ion-refresher>
```

Basically you can do something like this:

```
<ion-content padding>
    <ion-refresher (ionRefresh)="loadData($event)">
    // your custom code goes here:
        <div style="width: 100%; height: 64px; margin: auto">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xml:space="preserve">
                <svg:rect fill="#aaa" stroke="#eee" stroke-width="4" x="25" y="25" width="50" height="50"></svg:rect>
            </svg>
        </div>
    // end of your custom code
    </ion-refresher>
    <h2>{{header}}</h2>
    <p>
        This starter project comes with simple tabs-based layout for apps that are going to primarily use a Tabbed UI.
    </p>
    <p>
        Take a look at the <code>pages/</code> directory to add or change tabs,
    update any existing page or create new pages.
  </p>
</ion-content>
```

See code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-jtupjr

You can also check the source code for the refresher content component to understand how Ionic creates it and recreate yours:

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/core/src/components/refresher-content/refresher-content.tsx

Comment: thank you very much. it looks good. but the pulling down icon isn't displayed if we replace entire refresher content. there isn't a way to replace only the refresher icon?

Comment: There is, can you share what content you want?

Comment: basically you want to keep things like "text" etc that is displayed using normal options for refresher?

Comment: See if linked source for the refresher component makes it easy for you how to create same component and then modify it the way you want

Comment: yes, i want to keep things like "text", "pulling icon", etc

Comment: I thought about customizing the refresher component. But I couldn't the original source from node_modules. Could you let me know where the component is located in?

Comment: Did you see the source? Scroll down there and check the render part. Do you still need more help?